# nosql shema store design

Tags: database, mongodb, database-design, nosql, database-schema

i have a doubt.its about how the data to be stored in the mongodb.Actually i am learning mongodb with nodejs and express.i am building an delivery application.
i need to store daily orders.with date
**1st case**

for easier querying i made something like `date` as key and orders details as array

```
'2014-10-27': [{name, amount, ....}, {name, amount, ....}]


order = {name, amount, ....}
```

so it will be easy for me to get every orders for that day.

**2nd case**

create schema called orders and putting date as a field in the schema and indexing it so it will be easy for me to query.

```
[{name,amount, date}, {name, amount, date}]
```

which schema will be good for handling lots of data.i personally think **1st case** will be much more flexible.but still in a confusion to put  reference or actual object .sorry if i am wrong.i am still learning. i need some help from you guys to strengthen my learning. if the data become more which schema provide a good solution.

and if you guys feels like this is bad approach please help with your idea about the design.

Comment: In the first variant, you made date as key. Alright, but a key where?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev a key in orders schema. the order in formation will be in the value as array

Comment: So, with that design, ALL your orders will be in the same mongodb document?

Comment: yes.i need to get daily orders as quick as possible.with a given date

Comment: @SergioTulentsev so which approch should i take?

Comment: "which approach should I take" - Definitely not one where you put all your data into the same mongodb document.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182618/discussion-between-zabusa-and-sergio-tulentsev).